# How much work (time or documents returned) is expected from a given query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I receive a query fragment from a user, and add this fragment to a larger query.  I need to be able to return to the user an estimate of the "cost" (time, disk access, documents, etc) and perhaps notify the user that the query is too expensive.

I understand that if I do something like:

db.MyCollection.find({$and:[{"conditionsIRequire":true, {...query from the user}]}).explain()

I will receive a document that describes to calculated plan.  What I don't see in that output is the expected "cost".  It would be nice to know that prior to actually running the query.

Is it possible to get such information, either from the explain, or some other mechanism?

Comment: What is a "cost"? Honestly, you wrote a very unclear and not very well researched question and then have simply replaced your content with something equally unclear. If you expect to be told *"I think it's going to take this amount of time to retrieve results"* then you're looking in the wrong place. This is not the job of a query planner. Your "cost" as best I can estimate what you might actually mean, would need to factor in CPU, I/O performance, network overhead and a whole heap of things that are really just out of scope for what a database "should" be doing.

Comment: A query planner does "what it should". It tells you a general execution time and how many results should be expected. It can report on index usage if any, so you can have some insight into what to adjust. But if what you want is *"Siri/Alexa/Whatever, Is this query a good idea and how long would it take to run it?"*, then I believe you're chasing unicorns. Give us a bell when you have written the app which does this.

Comment: @NeilLunn When you said "It tells you a general execution time and how many results should be expected."  That's exactly what I'm looking for, but not able to find.  I can pass "executionStats" as a parameter to Explain, but that will result in the query executing.  I need a best guess from the optimizer prior to execution.